# Substitution when calculating limits

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I tried to calculate:

$$\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{e^{(1+k)t}-e^t}{k}$$

Apparently I can define: $h=k*t$ which gives:
$$t*\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{t+h}-e^t}{h}=t*\frac{d}{dt}e^t=te^t$$

QUESTION: Why can I define $h=k*t$? Or more specifically: why does the substitution still hold while $h$ is dependent on $t$?

The problem I have is that $k$ used to be a constant and now it is suddenly depending on $t$ because we define $k=\frac{h}{t}$

Comment: Why would it not hold? You're simply manipulating the thing inside the limit and then using the fact that we can factor out a constant.

Comment: If we substitute k=h/t then how can we be sure h/t goes to 0? h is constant, but t isn't...

Comment: But $t$ is constant. I don't know where you've got the idea that $t$ is not constant.

Comment: @Patrick Because it was originally a function of $t$?

Comment: Doesn't stop it being constant. $3k$ is a function of the constant $3$.